# MYSQL query: All records where user=jack from table `B` must be returned with the corresponding color matching `photo_id`

Tags: mysql

Here are two overly simplified version of 2 tables I'm using:

```
A:
+-------+-----------------------+ 
| id    | photo_id     | color  |
+-------+-----------------------+ 
| 1     | 100          | red    |
| 2     | 101          | blue   |
| 3     | 102          | green  |
+-------+-----------------------+

B:
+-------+-----------------------+ 
| id    | photo_id     | user   |
+-------+-----------------------+ 
| 1     | 100          | jack   |
| 2     | 101          | jill   |
| 3     | 102          | jack   |
| 4     | 103          | jill   |
| 5     | 104          | jack   |
| 6     | 105          | jack   |
| 7     | 106          | jack   |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

This is the query I'm running right now:

`SELECT * FROM B WHERE user='jack`';

But, now I need to get the following result

```
C:
+-------+-----------------------+--------+  
| id    | photo_id     | user   | color  |
+-------+-----------------------+--------+  
| 1     | 100          | jack   | red    |
| 2     | 102          | jack   | blue   |
| 3     | 104          | jack   | green  |
| 4     | 105          | jack   |        |  
| 5     | 106          | jack   |        |
+-------+-----------------------+--------+
```

All records where user=jack from table `B` must be returned with the corresponding color matching `photo_id`.

How can this be done?

Comment: I don't understand the table relationship. Can photos have multiple colors? From the sample you have, it looks like color could become a column of B.

Comment: @Matchu: As I said this is a simplified version. In reality, there are dozens of other columns. And yes, photo color is not unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but here goes:

```
SELECT * FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON A.photo_id = B.photo_id WHERE user = 'jack'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from B LEFT JOIN A using(photo_id) where B.user = 'jack';
```

Comment: An inner join wouldn't return rows without colors, right? That doesn't seem to match the OP's desired behavior.